# Remo.TV control LED with RaspberryPi

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I recently found this www.remo.tv website. It's actually awesome, exactly what I was looking for. I was able to pair it up with my RaspberryPi 3B+ and now I can see the camera. But how can I control let's say just 4 LEDs with the buttons below camera view? (WSAD) I don't get it.

Thanks a lot

Pavol
[image: remo.tv]

Answer (score 1):

At the bottom of your page, there is a option to "edit buttons", it takes in JSON format and allows you to customize the interface.